# How to customize an upset graph with stacked bars (size, legend, combo order)

Tags: python, upsetplot

I am trying to figure out in this example (https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/plot_discrete.html) how to:

1. change the size of the figure
2. move the legend at the upper left corner
3. define the order of the data in the combination matrix
   Has anyone any idea how to perform the above tasks when the UpSet graph has stacked bar?

*Additionally, has the plotly version of upset any "hue" feature?*

Comment: Also, in the same example the ```colors``` argument does not work...